# QNAmaker max amount of QNA pairs

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am generating a large PDF with questions for multi-turn.

I am doing this via the browser, it takes quite a while to update and in the end it says that it is still running in the background.

To check when it finished I made an api call to get the details of the operation. Eventually this returns that the state is failed with no sort of error code.

When I check my QnA pairs I have exactly 1000, which seems like it isn't a random number.

But I can't find anything about a limit of QnA pairs anywhere, it should be unlimited is what I've found.

Am I doing something wroung or what's going on here?

---

edit

When I query the server statistics this is the answer I get. The quota for the documentCount is null which should mean it's unlimited.

```
` {
    "@odata.context": "mylink",
    "counters": {
        "documentCount": {
            "usage": 2000,
            "quota": null
        },
        "indexesCount": {
            "usage": 2,
            "quota": 3
        },
        "indexersCount": {
            "usage": 0,
            "quota": 3
        },
        "dataSourcesCount": {
            "usage": 0,
            "quota": 3
        },
        "storageSize": {
            "usage": 1714194,
            "quota": 52428800
        },
        "synonymMaps": {
            "usage": 1,
            "quota": 3
        }
    },
    "limits": {
        "maxFieldsPerIndex": 1000,
        "maxIndexerRunTime": "PT1M",
        "maxFileExtractionSize": 16777216,
        "maxFileContentCharactersToExtract": 32768,
        "maxFieldNestingDepthPerIndex": 10,
        "maxComplexCollectionFieldsPerIndex": 40,
        "maxComplexObjectsInCollectionsPerDocument": 3000
    }
} `
```

---

edit 2

I had some duplicate questions, I deleted those and refactored some questions to subquestions. I don't really know why, but now the upload succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [QnA Maker Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/limits) page, the following limitations are applied to the content of a knowledge base:

> ```
> Length of answer text: 25,000
> Length of question text: 1,000
> Length of metadata key/value text: 100
> Supported characters for metadata name: Alphabets, digits and _
> Supported characters for metadata value: All except : and |
> Length of file name: 200
> Supported file formats: ".tsv", ".pdf", ".txt", ".docx", ".xlsx".
> Maximum number of alternate questions: 300
> Maximum number of question-answer pairs: Depends on the Azure Cognitive Search tier chosen. A question and answer pair maps to a document on Azure Cognitive Search index.
> URL/HTML page: 1 million characters
> ```

The important part being "*A question and answer pair maps to a document on Azure Cognitive Search index.*"

Documentation is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits).

So if you're on the free tier you could be hitting the max runtime limit of either 1-3 minutes per indexer OR 1 minute for the free services as per superscript 1 under the table.

You could try calling [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-service-statistics) for more information, and also ensure that you are under the [document size limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#document-size-limits-per-api-call).

**Edit**

It might pay to review the QnA Maker [data source guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/knowledge-base), as well as the specific guidelines for structured PDF content [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/content-types). There is also a [formatting guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-document-format-guidelines).

> QnA Maker identifies sections and subsections and relationships in the
>   file based on visual clues like:
>
> ```
> font size
> font style
> numbering
> colors
> ```

If someone in the future is struggling with PDF formatting then I'd suggest trying out a `.docx`, `xlx` or `.tsv` formats as they allow you to be a lot more specific around what is a question, and what is an answer

For docs:

> alternating Questions and Answers per line, one question per line
>   followed by its answer in the following line

For spreadsheets:

> Question1     \t Answer1  \t Key1:Value1 | Key2:Value2

As per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-document-format-guidelines)

Comment: I added the service statistics in my original post. I'm not on a free tier so I should have unlimited documentCount. Also my pdf is 2.5MB so it shouldn't hit the size limit. I wish I could get more information when querying the operation details, it just says failed.

Comment: 1000 sounds suspiciously like an index/indexer limit and lines up with the value for "maxFieldsPerIndex" result - have you tried navigating to the Azure Search resource in the Azure Portal, then on the Overview pane go to Index or Indexers and try to inspect the created index to see how many fields are being generated? I feel it might be creating a new field per question. There are some common error codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-common-errors-warnings).

Comment: You could try creating an index [directly in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-create-index-portal#start-index-designer).

Comment: I'll check it out, the error did kinda fix itself now, after generating a new pdf with a slightly different structure, it just works and I have about 5000 QnA pairs.

Comment: @stilllearning I have updated my answer to include more information. Please upvote and accept if it was helpful. Also you should add an edit to your original post around what you changed in your document to fix it.